# How to Safe Cast within a Try-Catch Block

Tags: kotlin, casting, try-catch

Here is how to safe cast within a Try-Catch Block using Kotlin. This is a syntax issue. There is no answer related to this for Kotlin so I'll share this to save some time for others.

Usually, to safe cast, people use this format:

```
fun functionName() {
    if (propertyName is ClassName1) {
        val variableName2 = propertyName as ClassName1()
        propertyName.memberFunction()
    }
}
```

The following code will show when a compilation error arises (I might have shown too much but I want you guys to understand the context):

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import java.lang.Exception

class MainThread(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder, gameView: GameView): Thread() {
    private lateinit var surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder
    private lateinit var gameView: GameView
    private var running: Boolean = false
    private var canvas: Canvas? = null

    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        while(running) {
            try { 
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas() 
                synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gameView.update()
                    this.gameView.draw(canvas) // Error arises at this line
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null){
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Build Output Error reads:

```
Smart cast to 'Canvas' is impossible, 
because 'canvas' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to put the `as` keyword inside of the parenthesis.

The following code will show how to implement a smart cast in a try-catch block:

```
    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        while(running) {
            try { 
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas() 
                synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gameView.update()
if (canvas is Canvas)
                    this.gameView.draw(canvas as Canvas) // Note change
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null){
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```